# I want to know where cassy's error log is output

Tags: scalardb, cassy

When I run the command cassy in my project, it fails. I would like to know the cause of the failure, but I don't know where to output the error log.

I would like to know where or how I can define the output location for the cassy error log.

Here is the log when the cassy command fails.

```
$ grpcurl -plaintext -d '{"snapshot_id": "7bdb9aa0-79b7-4cd3-8e08-a400433740ec", "restore_type": 2, "cluster_id": "ScalarDL-b729c0d4-4e72-4e3a-9b1a-02ea3c05120c"}' cassy-1.project:20051 rpc.Cassy.RestoreBackup
{
  "status": "STARTED",
  "cluster_id": "ScalarDL-b729c0d4-4e72-4e3a-9b1a-02ea3c05120c",
  "target_ips": [
    "10.111.2.169",
    "10.111.2.89",
    "10.111.2.38"
  ],
  "snapshot_id": "7bdb9aa0-79b7-4cd3-8e08-a400433740ec",
  "restore_type": 2
}


$ grpcurl -plaintext -d '{"limit": 6, "cluster_id": "ScalarDL-b729c0d4-4e72-4e3a-9b1a-02ea3c05120c"}' cassy-1.staging.sidb.internal:20051 rpc.Cassy.ListRestoreStatuses
{
  "cluster_id": "ScalarDL-b729c0d4-4e72-4e3a-9b1a-02ea3c05120c",
  "entries": [
    {
      "target_ip": "10.111.2.169",
      "snapshot_id": "7bdb9aa0-79b7-4cd3-8e08-a400433740ec",
      "created_at": "1630382600714",
      "updated_at": "1630382621288",
      "restore_type": 2,
      "status": "FAILED"
    },
    {
      "target_ip": "10.111.2.38",
      "snapshot_id": "7bdb9aa0-79b7-4cd3-8e08-a400433740ec",
      "created_at": "1630382600714",
      "updated_at": "1630382604445",
      "restore_type": 2,
      "status": "FAILED"
    },
    {
      "target_ip": "10.111.2.89",
      "snapshot_id": "7bdb9aa0-79b7-4cd3-8e08-a400433740ec",
      "created_at": "1630382600714",
      "updated_at": "1630382618413",
      "restore_type": 2,
      "status": "FAILED"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think it should first describe what kind of environment are you running your system in. 
Have you checked the logs of cassy containers?
(check the stdout and /var/log)

Comment: I hadn't looked at the logs for cassy containers yet. I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I checked cassy's `/var/log` and found the error.

```
    PlacementException: java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /data/coordinator/state-67d21470c1d FileAlreadyExistsException: /data/coordinator/state-67d21470c1d/411eaa82845d4f31f7d32/md-53-big-Summary.db
```

↑I'm getting an error like the one shown above, and I found out that the cause is that the file already exists.

Comment: So I have an additional question.
Here is the cassandra configuration.
```
data_file_directories:
- /data
commitlog_directory: /commitlog
hints_directory: /data/hints
saved_caches_directory: /data/saved_caches
```

If I want to restore cassandra with data backed up with cassy, do I need to delete all directories under `data`,`commitlogs`,`hints` before doing the restore?

Comment: Yes.
https://github.com/scalar-labs/cassy/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#restore-backups-to-a-node

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to restore it with your help.